# Change logo of AdminLTE in django

Tags: python, django, adminlte

I am using AdminLTE in my django admin site. I want to change its logo to my site name and also want to change its redirect link. But not getting any help related to that. Please give the solution if anyone has an idea about that.

Comment: Share your template base code, so people can help you out

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the base template and override the `logo` block and `logo_href` block.

Complete description of all the possible blocks you can override are documented [here](http://django-adminlte2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates_and_blocks.html#adminlte-lib-main-header-html)